# Simple languages that are not of type-1?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

To present interesting type-0 grammars to my students, I am looking for a very simple example of a type-0 language (=recursively enumerable language) that is not of type-1 (=not context sensitive). I am hoping for a language that is generated by a very small grammar, like two or three very short production rules or something like that.

The most simple examples I could think of so far:

- The halting problem, or similar semi-decidable problems.
- Any ExpSpace-complete problem, since these are not decidable in nondeterministic linear Space, which equals type-1 languages.
- There are very small universal Turing Machines, but translating these into grammars gives a blow up again.

So for neither of these problems I see a simple way to encode them in a very short grammar or very small grammar.

Do you have any idea how to find such an example?

Comment: [Very closely related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/273/decidable-non-context-sensitive-languages?rq=1); duplicate?

Comment: The PCP may be worth a look.